# error 500 in php when upload is complete

Tags: php, file-upload, upload, internal-server-error, php-5.5

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
if(isset($_FILES['userfile']){
$file = $_FILES['userfile'];

//proprietà del file

$file_name = $file['name'];
$file_tmp = $file['tmp_name'];
$file_size = $file['size'];
$file_error = $file['error'];

// come gestire il file

$file_ext = explode(".",$file_name);
$file_ext = strtolower(end($file_ext));

$allowed = array("txt", "jpg", "csv");
// controlli vari
if ($file_ext, $allowed){
  if($file_error === 0){
    if($file_size <= 2097152){
        print_r($file_size);
      $file_name_new = uniqid("", true) . "." . $file_ext;
      $file_destination = "uploads/" . $file_name_new;

      if(move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $file_destination)){
        echo $file_destination;
        }
      }
    }
  }



}


 ?>
```

Hi, the problem is when i try to upload 1 file any dimension when upload end , show error 500 i think there is an error in the code pls can you ceck this code for error ?

p.s i have changed this parameter:

```
post_max_size  64M
upload_max_filesize 64M
max_input_time 3000
max_execution_time 3000
```

but nothing is happen

update: 
thanks for all reply tryed to running php -l file-name.php and i have corrected the error but now when i upload the file i have white screen after upload done.

Comment: look in the php error logs

Comment: some errors: `if(isset($_FILES['userfile']){`; `if ($file_ext, $allowed)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
if ($file_ext, $allowed)
```

to

```
if (in_array($file_ext, $allowed))
```

For other errors, try running `php -l file-name.php` to show you some other things which may be wrong with the syntax

Comment: thanks for the reply tryed to running php -l file-name.php and i have corrected the error but now when i upload the file i have white screen after upload done.

Comment: yes, this is because you have nothing which prints to the screen in that script. But if you check the necessary location in your filesystem, you should see the uploaded file. Try `echo`ing something or redirecting to another page that does.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a syntax error.

Change this line

```
if ($file_ext, $allowed){
```

to this:

```
if (in_array($file_ext, $allowed)) {
```

And it will execute I think.